# Tiff Editing: How to add text to existing tif file?

Tags: c#, .net, tiff, libtiff, libtiff.net

I am trying to add some random text to right top corner of the every tif image file. How I can do this using libtif.NET library.

Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with LibTiff.Net. The library is for decoding and encoding TIFF images. It is not designed to alter image contents in any way.

You can achieve your goal by:

1. decoding TIFF image into the System.Drawing.Bitmap instance (for example)
2. drawing text over the bitmap
3. converting the bitmap back into TIFF

Comment: Is there any other libraries available  to alter the image contents ?